# Really broken questions

Tags: discussion, edits

What should be done about really bad/popular questions?

For instance [Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c).  The supposition of the question is false, e.g *"Which browser has the largest harddrive?"*
Martin's comment is most telling:

> This is one of those questions where common knowledge is wrong.

Should I refactor the question to ask the question that was answered (Compiler inlining instead of using the C++ `inline` keyword)? Or should I just provide the correct answer and hope that it eventually makes it to top?

To make the situation worse the question owner has not logged in for 2.5 years.

Comment: Don't fix anything.  It's okay for a question to make all wrong assumptions.  It is expected that the questioner is not an expert, that's why he asked.  Only the answers matter, Brian's answer is good enough.  Leaving the comment was fine.

Answer (score 2):

It has always seemed to me that these questions are quintessential (or maybe septessential) 'broken windows'. However, the management takes another view. While a bunch of them have been swept into the dustbin of history or at least programmers.se, many other remain in place. They have high votes, so they are deletable only by a very large group of people. And closing them often fails due to re-opening due to lovers of the subjective.

Now, one man's meat is another man's poisson distribution, so the fact that *I* think that any number of these should join the dodo might simply reveal me as a crank.

I know, I should post some links, but I don't have any ready-to-hand.

Comment: Terrible - one man's meat etc. Please admonish yourself severely :-)

Comment: If you prefer a capricious alternative -- chacon a son goat.

Comment: Crossing swords with a master is always a mistake - I'll just go and put my head under a pillow for a while until it stops.